# How can I call API inside Adapter Android

Tags: android

In my application I have **RecyclerView** and into this recyclerview I want show image. 
But I haven't direct path for load image, I have id of image and I should send this id to another API for get image path. 
**I write below code in Adapter :**

```kotlin
class MyAdapter @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext private val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var items = emptyList<Result>()
    private val userToken by lazy { GoodPrefs.getInstance().getString(USER_TOKEN, "") }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) = holder.bind(items[position])

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = position

    override fun getItemId(position: Int) = position.toLong()

    inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        fun bind(item: Result) {
            binding.apply {
                //Title
                titleTxt.text = item.title?.replace("\"","")
                //File
                if (item.file != null) {
                    when (item.file.type) {
                        IMAGE -> {
                            thumbImg.isVisible = true
                            thumbLoading.isVisible = true
                            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                                ApiClient.getInstance().apisUseCase().getAvatarImage(userToken, item.file.id!!)
                                    .applyIoScheduler()
                                    .subscribe({
                                        thumbLoading.isVisible = false
                                        if (it.isSuccessful) {
                                            if (it.code() == 200) {
                                                if (it.body() != null) {
                                                    val decodedBytes = Base64.decode(it.body()!!.data!!.file, Base64.DEFAULT)
                                                    Glide.with(context)
                                                        .load(decodedBytes)
                                                        .override(900, 400)
                                                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
                                                        .into(thumbImg)
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }, {
                                        thumbLoading.isVisible = false
                                    })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun setData(data: List<Result>) {
        val adapterDiffUtils = BaseDiffUtils(items, data)
        val diffUtils = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(adapterDiffUtils)
        items = data
        diffUtils.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }
}
```

I have one problem, when scroll on items call api again.I want when called api and show this image, after when scroll items not call again this api and just show image.

How can I it? please help me

How can I it? please help me

Comment: what if you can get response in `pagination`. In pagination limit if `10` items are scrolled automatically you call api and then you got response of page `2` and another `10` items.

Comment: Check this:    
`paginate = Paginate.with(layoutBinding.rvBooking, this)
              .setLoadingTriggerThreshold(Constant.PAGE_PROGRESS_THRESHOLD)
              .setLoadingListItemCreator(new PaginationVerticalAdapter(mActivity))
              .setLoadingListItemSpanSizeLookup(new LoadingListItemSpanLookup() {
              @Override
              public int getSpanSize() {
              return Constant.PAGE_GRID_SPAN;
                 }
                   })
                .build();`

Comment: and then `notifyDataSetChanged();`